# Change the xtragrid detailsView type programmatically devepxress

Tags: c#, devexpress, master-detail, xtragrid

I have this code

```
private string _nom;
private string _reference;
private BindingList<Contact> _listContact = null;

public string Nom
{
  get { return _nom; }
  set { _nom = value; }
}

public string Reference
{
  get { return _reference; }
  set { _reference = value; }
}

public BindingList<Contact> ListContact
{
  get { return _listContact; }
  set { _listContact = value; }
}
```

And Ihave a function that return BindingList

In my XtraForm I have this

```
listPartenaire = Partenaires.getPartenairesObjectUsingLinq();
dgv.DataSource = listPartenaire;
```

Well with that, I have an xtraGrid filled by Partenaire in the MasterView, and with the Contact in the DetailsView

What I'm looking for is to change the type of the detailsview to CardView or something else with c#

any help please

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following help article should be helpful: [Specify Views to Represent Detail Data](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument5497)

Please check the example:
[How to: Replace a View Used to Represent a Specific Master-Detail Relationship](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument3058)